# System.OutOfMemoryException after creating a lot of UIElements from an XML on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory

Well, I'm new on Windows Phone.

I'm just reading a XML with a lot of data and keeping it on a static var.
When I make a loop to show the datas that I got from XML, I create 1 Canvas with 2 Textblocks inside it.

But the XML have almost 500 lines of information, so the app creates 500 Canvas and 1000 TextBlocks.
And when I try to move between pages the app got too slow, and sometimes freeze, and when I move from that page to another, the memory is not disposed, and almost all methods, crashs the app with OutOfMemory Exception.

I want to know if there's something I can do to dispose that memory used on the app when I navigate to another page, or if there's some way to use less memory showing all of these datas in the same XAML.

OBS: Just loading the page uses almost 130MB of memory, and the phone just holds 150MB for the app.

EDIT:

```
private void empilharParticipantes()
{

    string nomeTitulo, nomeEmpresa;
    int margin = 0;
    SolidColorBrush corTexto = new SolidColorBrush();
    corTexto.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 103, 103, 103);
    SolidColorBrush corCanvas = new SolidColorBrush();
    corCanvas.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 242, 242);

    items = from query in App.xmlParticipantes.Descendants("Participante")
            orderby query.Element("title").Value
            select new ABPI.Classes.Participantes
            {
                nome = (string)query.Element("title"),
                empresa = (string)query.Element("company"),
                email = (string)query.Element("email"),
                telefone = (string)query.Element("phone"),
                profissao = (string)query.Element("text"),
                endereco = (string)query.Element("address")
            };

                var itemsArray = items.ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.Count(); i++)
                {   
                    Canvas cnv = new Canvas { Name = itemsArray[i].nome, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, Height = 90, Width = 420, Margin = new Thickness(30, margin, 0, 0), Background = corCanvas };


                    if (itemsArray[i].nome.Length > 30)
                    {
                        nomeTitulo = itemsArray[i].nome.Substring(0, 30) + "...";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nomeTitulo = itemsArray[i].nome;
                    }

                    if (itemsArray[i].empresa.Length > 35)
                    {
                        nomeEmpresa = itemsArray[i].empresa.Substring(0, 35) + "...";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nomeEmpresa = itemsArray[i].empresa;
                    }

                    TextBlock titulo = new TextBlock { Text = nomeTitulo, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap, FontSize = 25, Foreground = corTexto };
                    Canvas.SetLeft(titulo, 30);
                    Canvas.SetTop(titulo, 15);

                    TextBlock empresa = new TextBlock { TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap, Text = nomeEmpresa, FontSize = 20, Foreground = corTexto };
                    Canvas.SetLeft(empresa, 30);
                    Canvas.SetTop(empresa, 45);

                    cnv.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(uriParametro);

                    cnv.Children.Add(titulo);
                    cnv.Children.Add(empresa);

                    content.Children.Add(cnv);

                    margin = margin + 100;

                }

                txtbusca2.ItemsSource = lista;

                ContentPanel.Height = margin;
                content.Height = margin;
                oScroll.Content = content;
```

After the loop, i put the Canvas (content) inside the ScrollViewer (oScroll), but when I leave the page, the memory is not disposed, so when I try to go to anywhere else, the app crashes with System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Post the container DataTemplate that are using to populate this.  Is it a ListView, Panorama, Pivot... etc etc.

Comment: well, I put each canvas created on a "main" canvas. After it, i put this main canvas on a Scrollviewer inside the "ContentPanel" grid. I will edit my post to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these controls explicitly. Handle `Unloaded` event or override `OnNavigatedFrom()` method and simply remove all children.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: I tried the OnNavigatedFrom and it's not working, the app didn't disposes the memory with LayoutRoot.Children.Clear()